# Multiply within same column

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like the following:

| label | value |
| --- | --- |
| student1 | 90 |
| student2 | 88 |
| student3 | 59 |
| student4 | 77 |

I am trying to multiply two values if they meet the condition.
For example, I want to multiply values for student 1 and 3 together. Then I want to multiply the values for student 2 and 4.

For the first criteria, I tried the following code:

```
select 
    case 
        when 
            max(label) = "student1" or max(label) = "student3" then exp(SUM(log(value))) else 0 end as nominator
from four_students_table
```

Unfortunately, it gives me the value of 0. I have also tried to just add them together, but got 0 again. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Expected output:

| numerator | denominator |
| --- | --- |
| 5,310 | 6,776 |

Comment: show expected output

Comment: Added it to the question @MikhailBerlyant

Comment: will there only be 4 students? You used a column `calc`  in your shared `sql` but this is not present in your shared dataset. What is `calc`?

Comment: @ggordon yes, there will only be 4 students.

Comment: Sorry "calc" should have been "value". I am going to fix it now. But even with that, I still get the value of 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I `case statement` as shown in the example below would assist in filtering what you would like to aggregrate.

The following fiddle provides your desired results:

```
CREATE TABLE four_students_table (
  label VARCHAR(8),
  value INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO four_students_table
  (label, value)
VALUES
  ('student1', '90'),
  ('student2', '88'),
  ('student3', '59'),
  ('student4', '77');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN label='student1' THEN value ELSE 0 END)*
    SUM(CASE WHEN label='student3' THEN value ELSE 0 END) as nominator,
    SUM(CASE WHEN label='student2' THEN value ELSE 0 END)*
    SUM(CASE WHEN label='student4' THEN value ELSE 0 END) as denominator
FROM
    four_students_table;
```

| nominator | denominator |
| --- | --- |
| 5310 | 6776 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ky7RospxBTFCRnm8LFgh4J/0)

Answer (score 0):

Consider below (I feel this is more inline with your intends/sample in your question)

```
select distinct
  round(exp(sum(if(label in ('student1', 'student3'), ln(value), 0)) over())) as nominator,
  round(exp(sum(if(label in ('student2', 'student4'), ln(value), 0)) over())) as denominator
from `project.dataset.four_students_table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]