# How to create estimate in bigquery using standard SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So in my situation, I have a table similar to this and I am trying to fill in the `cum_value` to create an estimate.

```
day |  %     |  value   | cum_value
----------------------------
1   |  100%  |   100    | 100
2   |  50%   |   75     | 175
3   |  30%   |   80     | 255
4   |  25%   |   95     | 350
5   |  20%   |   45     | 395
6   |  15%   |   65     | 460
7   |  13%   |   80     | 540
8   |  10%   |   95     | 635
9   |  10%   |   45     | 680
10  |  10%   |   75     | 755
11  |  8%    |   86     | 841
12  |  8%    |   48     | 889
13  |  5%    |   57     | 946
14  |  5%    |          | 
15  |  5%    |          | 
16  |  5%    |          | 
17  |  5%    |          | 
18  |  5%    |          | 
19  |  5%    |          | 
20  |  5%    |          | 
21  |  5%    |          | 
22  |  4%    |          | 
23  |  4%    |          | 
24  |  4%    |          | 
25  |  4%    |          | 
26  |  4%    |          | 
27  |  4%    |          | 
28  |  4%    |          | 
29  |  4%    |          | 
30  |  4%    |          | 
31  |  4%    |          |
```

Dataset query:

```
select 1 day, 1 percentage, 100 value, 100 cum_value UNION ALL
select 2 day, 0.5 percentage, 75 value, 175 cum_value UNION ALL
select 3 day, 0.3 percentage, 80 value, 255 cum_value UNION ALL
select 4 day, 0.25 percentage, 95 value, 350 cum_value UNION ALL
select 5 day, 0.2 percentage, 45 value, 395 cum_value UNION ALL
select 6 day, 0.15 percentage, 65 value, 460 cum_value UNION ALL
select 7 day, 0.13 percentage, 80 value, 540 cum_value UNION ALL
select 8 day, 0.1 percentage, 95 value, 635 cum_value UNION ALL
select 9 day, 0.1 percentage, 45 value, 680 cum_value UNION ALL
select 10 day, 0.1 percentage, 75 value, 755 cum_value UNION ALL
select 11 day, 0.08 percentage, 86 value, 841 cum_value UNION ALL
select 12 day, 0.08 percentage, 48 value, 889 cum_value UNION ALL
select 13 day, 0.05 percentage, 57 value, 946 cum_value UNION ALL
select 14 day, 0.05 percentage, null value, null cum_value UNION ALL
select 15 day, 0.05 percentage, null value, null cum_value UNION ALL
select 16 day, 0.05 percentage, null value, null cum_value UNION ALL
select 17 day, 0.05 percentage, null value, null cum_value UNION ALL
select 18 day, 0.05 percentage, null value, null cum_value UNION ALL
select 19 day, 0.05 percentage, null value, null cum_value UNION ALL
select 20 day, 0.05 percentage, null value, null cum_value UNION ALL
select 21 day, 0.05 percentage, null value, null cum_value UNION ALL
select 22 day, 0.04 percentage, null value, null cum_value UNION ALL
select 23 day, 0.04 percentage, null value, null cum_value UNION ALL
select 24 day, 0.04 percentage, null value, null cum_value UNION ALL
select 25 day, 0.04 percentage, null value, null cum_value UNION ALL
select 26 day, 0.04 percentage, null value, null cum_value UNION ALL
select 27 day, 0.04 percentage, null value, null cum_value UNION ALL
select 28 day, 0.04 percentage, null value, null cum_value UNION ALL
select 29 day, 0.04 percentage, null value, null cum_value UNION ALL
select 30 day, 0.04 percentage, null value, null cum_value UNION ALL
select 31 day, 0.04 percentage, null value, null cum_value
```

So, when `value` is not null I can use the value from `value` and accumulate it using the window function, but the tricky part is when `value` is null I need to use the latest `cum_value` and multiply it with the latest + 1 `%`.

For example, to fill `cum_value` in row 14 it should be 946 * 1.05 = 993.3. To fill `cum_value` in row 15 the calculation would be 993.3 & 1.05 (from row 15) = 1,042.97 and so on. This is something that should be quite straightforward if it was done in Excel/Gsheet ( *=IF(C15<>"", C15, (D14*B15)+D14)* ). But I can't seem to find the workaround in SQL (BigQuery)

The expected end result would be something like this

```
day |  %    |   value   | cum_value
----------------------------------
1   |  100% |   100     | 100
2   |  50%  |   75      | 175
3   |  30%  |   80      | 255
4   |  25%  |   95      | 350
5   |  20%  |   45      | 395
6   |  15%  |   65      | 460
7   |  13%  |   80      | 540
8   |  10%  |   95      | 635
9   |  10%  |   45      | 680
10  |  10%  |   75      | 755
11  |  8%   |   86      | 841
12  |  8%   |   48      | 889
13  |  5%   |   57      | 946
14  |  5%   |           | 993.3
15  |  5%   |           | 1042.965
16  |  5%   |           | 1095.11325
17  |  5%   |           | 1149.868913
18  |  5%   |           | 1207.362358
19  |  5%   |           | 1267.730476
20  |  5%   |           | 1331.117
21  |  5%   |           | 1397.67285
22  |  4%   |           | 1453.579764
23  |  4%   |           | 1511.722954
24  |  4%   |           | 1572.191873
25  |  4%   |           | 1635.079547
26  |  4%   |           | 1700.482729
27  |  4%   |           | 1768.502039
28  |  4%   |           | 1839.24212
29  |  4%   |           | 1912.811805
30  |  4%   |           | 1989.324277
31  |  4%   |           | 2068.897248
```

Comment: it is not clear from your sample - can rows with non-null values appear after some rows with null values?

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant, apologies for being unclear. In my case, no, rows with non-null values can't appear after rows with null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my understanding - in real case `cum_value` DOES NOT exists and needs to be calculate from dadta with `day`, `percentage` and `value` columns. So relying on `cum_value` is not correct way to go!

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  sum(value) over(order by day) *
  if(not value is null, 1, 
    exp(sum(ln(1 + percentage)) over (partition by value is null order by day))
  ) cum_value
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In lieu of corrections to another answer here, here is my bug fix of that existing answer.

Credit to @GordonLinoff for the solution to "cumulative product":

- `EXP(SUM(LN(1+percentage)))`

Which gives...

```
select
  t.*,
  coalesce(
    cum_value,
    (
      max(cum_value) over ()
      *
      exp(sum(ln(1 + percentage)) over (partition by grp order by day))
    )
  )
    as estimate_product
from
(
  select
    t.*,
    CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as grp
  from
    test t
)
  t;
```

Comment: Standard ISO SQL-2016 compliant. (Except the day column name, which is a reserved word and needs to be delimited as `"day"`, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words)

Answer (score -2):

You can approximate the product by using logs and exponents.  To start, define the groups where there are `NULL` values, which you can do with a conditional sum:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(cum_value,
                (max(cum_value) over (partition by grp) *
                 exp(sum(ln(1 + percentage)) over (partition by grp order by day) -
                     first_values(cum_value) over (partition by grp order by day)
                    )
                ) as estimate_product
from (select t.*,
             count(value) over (order by day) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: There seem to be a couple of issues...   `grp` probably should just be `CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`?  The brackets around `EXP(SUM(LOG)))` appear wrong?  Should be `1+percentage` rather than `1+value`?  The SQL Server version of my bug-fix of this is here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6066693b71be9345dfd7dfccf7e5d3c2 *(`log()` and `ln()`may be the only incompatibilities?)*

Comment: @MatBailie - why don't you post your answer here?!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - Because `EXP(SUM(LOG()))` didn't occur to me, all I did is bug fix someone else's answer, for which they should still get credit.

Comment: disagree with this way of thinking - check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/68966769/5221944 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/68900524/5221944 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/68005245/5221944 - does it mean noone else can now use this approach?! especially in such a wrong way! I recommend you to post your answer, so we have here working/correct one!

Comment: @MatBailie . . . The definition of `grp` is correct.

Comment: Still has `1+value` where it should be `1+percentage`.  Still has a missing `)` for the `COALESCE()`.  `- first(value)` should be `- ln(1+first(percentage))` : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=109ecab8eaec591fb0e5b921ad993dbd

Comment: @MatBailie . . . Do you realize that the OP changed the question since I answered?

Comment: But, a missing `)` has nothing to do with the OP.  And the OP never changed which column is a percentage and which is a scalar value to be cumulatively summed.  And the `-first(x)` needing to be `-ln(first(x))` is nothing to do with the OP either. 
 I'm not trying to criticise, just point out bugs that I can see.  I'll happily delete all my comments, but at the point I commented, the answer didn't even run.

Comment: i suggest just deleting this answer!